# How can I get all the points on a line in OpenCvSharp?

Tags: c#, opencv

There is a line from Point(x1, y1) to Point(x2, y2). And I wanna get all the points on that line.

I know, OpenCv has LineIterator. But I couldn't find how can I use it on C#?

There is sample usage in C++ (For giving an idea):

```
LineIterator it(img, pt1, pt2, 8);
for(int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, ++it)
{
    Point pt= it.pos(); 
    //Draw Some stuff using that Point pt
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use enumerator of a `LineIterator` instance:

```
// You can pass connectivity as constructor argument. Default is 8.
foreach (var lip in new LineIterator(img, pt1, pt2)) {
    Point p = lip.Pos;
    // Use appropriate type for generic GetValue<of T>().
    byte v = lip.GetValue<byte>();
}}
```

For more information check OpenCvSharp [source code](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/blob/master/src/OpenCvSharp/modules/imgproc/LineIterator.cs). In current version (3.2.0.20170324) `LineIterator` properties doesn't work. Only use `LineIterator.Point` (`lip` in my code snippet) properties.